# Second Session ENGINE without expiry date

Tags: python, django, session, session-variables

I have `Product` model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'products/images', null = True, blank = True)
    image_url = models.URLField(null = True, blank = True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    product_views = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
```

In each user view, I add one to `product_views`. `views.py`:

```
def product_detail_view(request, id):
    if 'views' not in request.session:
        request.session['views'] = []
    arr = request.session['views']

    # obj = Product.objects.get(id = id)
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id = id)
    if id not in arr:
        arr.append(id)
        request.session['views'] = arr
        obj.product_views = obj.product_views + 1
        obj.save()

    context = {
        'object': obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/detail.html', context)
```

I set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 86400` in `settings.py`. It works great. But there's one problem. In my app user can log in and after a day, he has to log in again. I wanted to add `Remember me` checkbox to my log in, but here's problem. I can't set specific expire time for specific key. So I have to make my own 2nd Session Engine. I wrote this:

```
class ProductViews(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'views', null = True, blank = True)
    viewer = models.CharField(max_length = 36, null=True, blank=True) # Here, I can take IP if viewer isn't logged in
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'viewed_products', null = True, blank = True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default = django.utils.timezone.now)
```

I can check expiry time by this:

```
    dateta = product_v.datetime

    time_now = datetime.datetime.now(dateta.tzinfo)  # current time
    time_now = time_now - timedelta(days = 1)
    if dateta < time_now:  # check if stored time exceeds 1 day
        product_v.delete(keep_parents = True)
```

I want to set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` to 1 month, but it will affect the `product_views`. It will not be able to count after 1 day, it will count after 1 month, that's not OK. I don't know, will it work so good as default DB Session Engine. Do you have any ideas about it? I will be thankfull for any help.

Comment: You want to store the products a user has viewed forever?

Comment: No, I set SESSION_COOKIE_AGE to 86400. It will reset user view after 1 day, so user can view it again and `product_views` will continue counting. It is like this:
You view it today, `product_views` will be 1.
You view it tomorrow, `product_views` will be 2.
The day after tomorrow, it will be 3 and etc. It increases if the user didn't see it today, else it can be increased tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There's no need to make 2nd Session Engine, because it will take much time, and it will be difficult to edit it by the time.
Here's a much easier way:
In `middleware.py` I put:

```
class ViewsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        check_view(request)

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response


def check_view(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
    print(request.session['viewed'])
    print(request.session['views'])
    if 'viewed' not in request.session or request.session['viewed'] != now.day:
        request.session['viewed'] = now.day
        request.session['views'] = []

        obj, created = SiteView.objects.get_or_create(
                current = f'{now.year} {now.month} {now.day}',
                defaults = {'current': f'{now.year} {now.month} {now.day}', 'views': 1}
        )
        if not created:
            obj.views += 1
            obj.save()
```

And in `details_view` (when product is viewed):

```
def detail_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, pub_id = id)
    if 'views' not in request.session:
        request.session['views'] = []
    arr = request.session['views']
    if id not in arr:
        arr.append(id)
        request.session['views'] = arr
        obj.product_views = obj.product_views + 1
        obj.save()

    context = {
        'title' : obj.title,
        'object': obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/products/detail.html', context)
```

I hope, it will you.